# About UK Visitor Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, study

I am from India and studying for a master's in France. I am working as an intern in France on a programming language and I got an invitation letter from a UK university for an international conference. The conference is all related to my internship and I want to attend it.

Is it possible to apply for a visitor's visa from Paris because I am a student at Paris Saclay University? Could you please tell me if it is possible to apply on the basis of an invitation letter?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here [Apply for UK visa while not in my home country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36546/apply-for-uk-visa-while-not-in-my-home-country) You can apply as a visitor in any country that you entered legally AND has an Entry Clearance Issuing Post, that would include France.