# Can I apply for a UK visit visa as a foreign student in Malaysia?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, applications, nigerian-citizens

My elder brother wants me to visit him in the UK. He has been a British citizen for over 30 years. I am studying in Malaysia. I am from Nigeria.

Should I apply from Malaysia or go back home and apply for my visa? I am financially secure but unemployed. If I apply from Malaysia, I have all the documents from my school and financial statements, but if I go back home, I'm unable to back up my documents and I can't use my Malaysia permit to apply in Nigeria.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36546/apply-for-uk-visa-while-not-in-my-home-country

Comment: You’re the same person who wants to go to school in Canada?

Comment: Yes .. I am @The Zealot

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a UK Visit Visa from any location where applications are accepted, it does not need to be in your native country. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules You’ll have to declare your previous US visa denial, which will significantly lower your chances of success (in all likelihood, to zero).

Comment: Alright. I will do that, but do you think that would affect my Uk visa application.

Comment: @J.Spinners It’s not automatic but coupled with your employment status and citizenship of a high risk country IMHO your application is very unlikely to be approved. Having a UK sponsor won’t make any difference, you need to qualify in your own right.

Comment: I have been denied the Czech Republic and Italy visa too. Do I have to list all this denies out while applying? cause I was just told the purpose of traveling wasn't justified for them to approved my application for the Czech Republic and Italy and I was ban in the USA for misrepresentation details on my passport.

Comment: I am unemployed and studying in my MBA Program over here in Malaysia

Comment: @J.Spinners Yes, you do. The UK visa application form asks “Have you ever been refused a visa /deported/required to leave/removed/refused entry at the border for any country other than the UK”. IMHO with this history you would be wasting your money applying.