# When will my Uk visa Application decision come?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a Uk visa on the 29th of August 2018 and I got a mail from the embassy said "A decision has been made on your application and your documents are being returned to the Visa Application Centre (VAC).  You will be contacted again by the VAC once these documents have been received and they are ready for you to collect. If you have chosen to have your documents couriered to you, these will be despatched by the VAC once they have been received.

Please do not attend the application center until you have been contacted by the VAC.  UKVI contact details can be found at". I was told 15 days meaning 15 business day i think. There are 3 days holiday in the country where i live from the timeline. It's about 8days and don't know what to get back. i don't know it's to soon to hear back.

Comment: Take a chill pill and go collect your documents when you are told to. Sometimes they decide on an application within 1 day.  So 8 days are much more than enough for many cases. That does not indicate the outcome.

Comment: @Hanky Panky . Thanks, would have to wait until i get my documents back

Comment: Yep, only then will you know the outcome. Even the clerk who hands you over the passport does not know before you what's the decision.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is classic post submission anxiety.

Comment: It’s also highly unlikely the OP will get the visa, based on all his previous questions and refused visa history. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119827/can-i-apply-for-a-uk-visit-visa-as-a-foreign-student-in-malaysia

Comment: @Traveller. You feel i wouldn't get the visa right.